# Dropdown symbol is overlapping with text in AngularJS 1

Tags: angularjs

I have a `dropdown` which has elements of more characters. In order to display it in the `dropdown` I have to decided to add 3 dots as it has more characters.

When I come back to edit the value of `dropdown` (logout and login and try to edit), the text is overlapping with `dropdown` symbol.

[(Wrong tick mark in img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZhVH.png)

```
<div style="margin-top:3.2px;" class="shortdropdownContainer weak">
    <div  class="selectdivshort weak" style="display;none">
        <label>
            <select class="chooseCoun ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"
                ng-init="init()"
                data-ng-model="selectedType"
                data-ng-options="x.value for x in businessType" >
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
    <p id="dropdownmessage" class="editCorporate weak">
        {{selectedType.value}}
    </p>
</div>
```

currently the code looks like above.

I want dropdown to act in the same way even if i come back to edit mode.
dropdown should look like [(Right tick mark in img).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZhVH.png)

Comment: make a Plunker or Fiddle for your issue and share it.